# Laravel. How to get two additional records in the relations from the same table as the main query?

Tags: laravel

I have a model `Article` (id, title, content, created_at).

I can do:

```
$articles = Article::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->skip($start)->take($length)
            ->get(['id', 'title', 'content', 'created_at']);
```

But I want to get 2 random additional articles for each article . How can I do it?

For example:

```
{
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'title1'
    content: 'qwqwqwqwqwqwqwq',
    created_at: '2022-11-25 14:04:35',
    related: {
              id: 77,
              title: 'title77'
              content: 'fhhhfh',
              created_at: '2022-11-26 17:04:57',
             },
             {
              id: 15,
              title: 'title15'
              content: 'kkkkkkkk',
              created_at: '2022-11-27 15:04:45',
             },
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `get()` method of `Eloquent's Builder` returns a `collection` ([Check here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L498)), You can use `map()` method to add random items you mentioned.

```
Article::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->skip($start)->take($length)
        ->get(['id', 'title', 'content', 'created_at'])->map(function ($articles){
        $articles['related'] = Article::inRandomOrder()->take(2)->get();
        return $articles;
    });
```

Comment: This will result in an N+1 problem and a lot of unnecessary queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can just simple assign the related articles in a loop:

```
foreach ($articles as $article) {
    $article->related = $articles->whereNotIn('id', [$article->id])->random(2)->values();
}
```

If you want to load the related articles by relationship, you can create a column named `related_id` in `article` table and set default value to `1`

Then, create a relationship on `Article` model:

```
public function related(){
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class, 'related_id', 'related_id');
}
```

Then, you can load the related articles by using `with` function (remember to add `related_id` to the array of `get` function):

```
$articles = Article::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->with(['related' => function($query){
    $query->inRandomOrder()->take(2);
}])->skip($start)->take($length)->get(['id', 'title', 'content', 'created_at', 'related_id']);
```